# Fetch not working on React Native Android debug

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to create a very simple ReactNative app to play around with GraphQL and RN on an Android (I'm already familiar with getting it to work on an iPhone).

But I'm running into a problem -- my root component places a `get` request to an API. Although that request works perfectly when I spin up an XCode simulator, it completely fails when I run the Android version on my phone.

> The Android/iOS versions are for now completely identical. The two index files both use `react-native-router-flux` and are identical, and they import shared components.

Here's the simplified code of the component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      source: 'myGraphQLEndpoint'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.drill) { return null; }

    this.serverRequest = fetch(this.state.source)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          drill: json.data.drill
        });
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    const { drill } = this.state;
    if (!drill) { return null; }
    ... some view stuff
  }
```

On my iOS simulator, this works perfectly. On my Android phone, it never sets state, and so doesn't get past the `if (!drill)` line. If I instead set the state to the expected API data directly (instead of making an actual call), the Android app works just fine (with the non-live data).

The phone IS connected to the internet.

Any idea what's wrong?

PS -- I've tried a number of variants, including:

- Changing the request to have only one `.then`, which calls `response.json().data.drill`.
- Assigning the response to a variable defined outside of the request, and setting `state` to equal that (which sets state to what looks like a response buffer `[42, 36, ...` which can't be printed to the screen.

No dice.

Comment: it's because of a bug in 0.22+ react-native versions, did you try to downgrade?

Comment: I kicked on this particular project for now. Think I'll wait to upgrade instead. Thanks!